# Concatenate row values in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: pandas, dataframe, merge, concatenation

I have a problem with Pandas' DataFrame Object.
I have read first excel file and I have DataFrame like this:
[First DataFrame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zoUvD.png)

And read second excel file like this:
[Second DataFrame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GX6EB.png)

I need to concatenate rows and it should like this:
[Third DataFrame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dK5LU.png)

I have code like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
x1 = pd.ExcelFile("x1.xlsx")
df1 = pd.read_excel(x1, "Sheet1")
x2 = pd.ExcelFile("x2.xlsx")
df2 = pd.read_excel(x2, "Sheet1")
result = pd.merge(df1, df2, how="outer")
```

The second df just follow the first df,how can I get the style with dataframe like the third one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`merge` does not concatenate the dfs as you want, use `append` instead.

```
ndf = df1.append(df2).sort_values('name')
```

You can also use concat:

```
ndf = pd.concat([df1, df2]).sort_values('name')
```

Comment: Thanks for answer!But the result isn't that I want,I need put the same name with the first id in each row togather.

Comment: IIUC, you can then use sort_values('name').

Comment: df3=pd.concat([df1, df2],sort_values('name'))
Like this?